# CouchDb Error gen_server call get_state 94897 infinity

Tags: couchdb

Today when I'm trying to connect to my application, I've found an error in CouchDB in a log file

For any views that I used, when I'm trying to call any of them I got this error without more details :

`gen_server,call,[<0.22224.0>,{get_state,94897},infinity]}`

I don't know how to resolve this. Maybe some system files of CouchDB was modified?

Comment: You should probably reach CouchDB slack for this kind of error.